# "Unable to open file"

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

This is one of my first projects using QML: I started making a simple game character and a few rooms, and to make the walls'hitboxes I stored them all into a file and included a FileIO class I saw in this site, adapted to return the entire file instead of just one line.
The program, though, tells me it isn't able to open the file (I have put it in the project's directory)

```
//main.qml (ignore line 5)

import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.12
import FileIO 1.0

// Whats this? UwU a byzantiuwm?!?!!? UwU i wove  byzantiuwm, especiwwawwy in the #memes channew wewe byzantiuwm is the tawk of ze town! OwO

Rectangle {
    width: 639
    height: 480
    id: sus // I hate myself
    color: "#00ff00"
    Shape {
        property string d: "S"
        property int room: 1
        id: player
        x: xPos
        y: yPos
        z: 1
        visible: true
        property int xPos: 297
        property int yPos: 219
        parent: sus
        width: 45
        height: 45
        focus: true
        Keys.onPressed:
        {
            if(event.key === Qt.Key_Down){
                yPos+=3; d="S"
            }
            if(event.key === Qt.Key_Up){
                yPos-=3; d="N"
            }
            if(event.key === Qt.Key_Left){
                xPos-=3; d="W"
            }
            if(event.key === Qt.Key_Right){
                xPos+=3; d="E"
            }
            event.accepted = true;
        }
        ShapePath{
            strokeColor: "transparent"
            fillColor: "transparent"
            PathLine{x:45 ;y: 0}
            PathLine{x:45 ;y:45}
            PathLine{x: 0 ;y:45}
        }
        Image {
            id: sprite
            parent: player
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            smooth: false
            source: "Player/Player_" + player.d + ".png"
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: background
        x: 0
        y: 0
        z: 0
        width: 639
        height: 480
        visible: true
        smooth: false
        parent: sus
        source: "Rooms/" + player.room + ".png"
        fillMode: Image.Stretch
    }

    Shape {
        id: wallHitBox
        x: 0
        y: 0
        z: 50
        width: sus.width
        height: sus.height
        //visible: false
        FileIO{
            id: fileReader
            source: "Rooms/Hitboxes_or_something.txt"
            onError: {console.log(msg)}
        }
        property var the: fileReader.read()
        ShapePath{
            strokeColor: "transparent"
            fillColor: "blue" //"transparent"
            PathSvg{
                path: wallHitBox.the[player.room];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
//fileio.cpp

#include "fileio.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

FileIO::FileIO(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{

}

QVector<QString> FileIO::read()
{
    if (mSource.isEmpty()){
        emit error("source is empty");
        return QVector<QString>();
    }

    QFile file(mSource);
    QVector<QString> fileContent;
    if ( file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) ) {
        QString line;
        QTextStream t( &file );
        do {
            line = t.readLine();
            fileContent.resize(fileContent.size()+1);
            fileContent[fileContent.size()] = line;
         } while (!line.isNull());

        file.close();
    } else {
        emit error("Unable to open the file");
        return QVector<QString>();
    }
    return fileContent;
}

bool FileIO::write(const QString& data)
{
    if (mSource.isEmpty())
        return false;

    QFile file(mSource);
    if (!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate))
        return false;

    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << data;

    file.close();

    return true;
}
```

```
#define FILEIO_H

#include <QObject>

class FileIO : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Q_PROPERTY(QString source
               READ source
               WRITE setSource
               NOTIFY sourceChanged)
    explicit FileIO(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE QVector<QString> read();
    Q_INVOKABLE bool write(const QString& data);

    QString source() { return mSource; };

public slots:
    void setSource(const QString& source) { mSource = source; };

signals:
    void sourceChanged(const QString& source);
    void error(const QString& msg);

private:
    QString mSource;
};

#endif // FILEIO_H
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You declare `fileContent` but never add anything to it.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add that line

Comment: Updated the question, I realized that the problem is another

Comment: Did you add `qmlRegisterType` in  your main.cpp ?

Comment: and also why you put set function in public slots ???

Comment: 1) I did
2) Idk, I found it here